# php script to push data 2d array

Tags: php, json

I am almost there to add the data into my file.But I am trying ti figure out the exact syntax..Any help highly appreciated..

My php script

```
$inp = file_get_contents('jsontrail.json');

$tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
//adding to the matchid index of matches array
$matchid=3;
$arrne['games']['matches'][$matchid]['winner'] ="winner";
$arrne['games']['matches'][$matchid]['player1id'] ="player1id";
$arrne['games']['matches'][$matchid]['player2id'] ="player2id";
array_push($tempArray,$arrne );
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('jsontrail.json', $jsonData);
print_r( $inp);
```

my valid json file

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "name": "Moldova",
        "image": "/Images/Moldova.jpg",
        "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
    },
    /* repeat */
],
"games": [
    {
        "matches": [
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 1,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            /* repeat */
        ]
    },
    {
        "matches": [
            {
                "player1id": 0,
                "player2id": 1,
                "winner": "*"
            },
            /* repeat */
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to add data to already exist array,

in games->first_match_array->mymatch_id_input->push_data_here.

After execution, this is what i get in screen

```
{
    "players":
    [
        {
            "name":"Moldova",
            "image":"\/Images\/Moldova.jpg",
            "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
        },
        /* repeat */
    ]
    ,
    "games":
    [
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "player1id":0,
                    "player2id":1,
                    "winner":"*"
                },
                /* repeat */
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "player1id":0,
                    "player2id":1,
                    "winner":"*"
                },
                /* repeat */
            ]
        }
    ],
    "0":
    {
        "games":
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "3":
                    {
                        "winner":"winner",
                        "player1id":"player1id",
                        "player2id":"player2id"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

the above is got with array_push..the next code I got with array_merge

```
{
    "players":
    [
        {
            "name":"Moldova",
            "image":"\/Images\/Moldova.jpg",
            "roll_over_image":"tank.jpg"
        },
        /* repeat */
    ],
    "games":
    [
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "player1id":0,
                    "player2id":1,
                    "winner":"*"
                },
                /* repeat */
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "player1id":0,
                    "player2id":1,
                    "winner":"*"
                },
                /* repeat */
            ]
        }
    ],
    "0":
    {
        "games":
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "3":
                    {
                        "winner":"winner",
                        "player1id":"player1id",
                        "player2id":"player2id"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "1":
    {
        "games":
        {
            "matches":
            [
                {
                    "3":
                    {
                        "winner":"winner",
                        "player1id":"player1id",
                        "player2id":"player2id"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Please help,seems simple but cannot find the exact code to do it..Please help..

Comment: You didn't said what the problem/error was, but I _guess_ you may want [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), not [`array_push`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: I tried but doesn'y seems to work..My problem is that this code add the data at the end of file.. @Passerby

Comment: Can you demonstrate the original JSON, your `$arrne` content, and your expected result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your malformed json string, it is not constructed properly, try this

```
$str = '{
"players": [
{
    "name": "Moldova",
    "image": "/Images/Moldova.jpg",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Georgia",
    "image": "/Images/georgia.gif",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Belarus",
    "image": "/Images/Belarus.gif",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Armenia",
    "image": "/Images/armenia.png",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Kazahstan",
    "image": "/Images/kazahstan.gif",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Russia",
    "image": "/Images/russia.gif",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Ukraine",
    "image": "/Images/ukraine.png",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Uzbekistan",
    "image": "/Images/uzbekistan.gif",
    "roll_over_image": "tank.jpg"
}
],
"games": [
{
    "matches": [
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 1,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 2,
        "player2id": 3,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 4,
        "player2id": 5,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 6,
        "player2id": 7,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 2,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 4,
        "player2id": 6,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 4,
        "winner": 4
    }
    ]
},
{
    "matches": [
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 1,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 2,
        "player2id": 3,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 4,
        "player2id": 5,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 6,
        "player2id": 7,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 2,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 4,
        "player2id": 6,
        "winner": "*"
    },
    {
        "player1id": 0,
        "player2id": 4,
        "winner": 0
    }
    ]
}]}';
```

it will work if you use this.

Comment: @ chandresh_cool I formatted the way you said and I also changed the code to this..

Comment: $inp = file_get_contents('jsontrail.json');
   
   $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
   //adding to the matchid index of matches array
   $matchid=3;
   $arrne['str']['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['winner'] ="winner";
   $arrne['str']['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['player1id'] ="player1id";
   $arrne['str']['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['player2id'] ="player2id";
   array_merge($tempArray,$arrne );
   $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
   file_put_contents('jsontrail.json', $jsonData);
   print_r( $inp);

Comment: I struggling with this simple insert for very long time..plsss help!! @chandresh_cool

Comment: @chandresh_cool It would be nice if you also point out what change you had made.

Comment: I used this one                                            $arrne['str']['games']['matches'][0][$matchid]['winner'] ="winner"; used str

Comment: that is all fine the problem is in json string where at the end u have to add extra ]}

Comment: no it was not there when u initially asked question and it was required so i added it when replied with my answer

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're messing up with the key order,</strike>

```
$arrne['games']['matches'][$matchid]['winner']
```

Should be

```
$arrne['games'][$matchid]['matches']['winner']
```

You're missing a numeric index,

```
$arrne['games']['matches'][$matchid]['winner']
```

Should either be

```
$arrne['games'][]['matches'][$matchid]['winner']
```

Or be

```
$arrne['games'][$matchid]['matches'][]['winner']
```

Because in your origin JSON, you have

```
"games": [
    {
        "matches": [
        /* ... */
        ]
    },
    {
        "matches": [
        /* ... */
        ]
    }
```

So the structure is `games->[index]->matches->[index]`, not `games->matches->[index]`.

Also, simple `array_merge` wouldn't work, you need [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php);

Example code:

```
$json=<<<JSON
...
JSON;
$tempArray=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($tempArray);
$matches=array(
    "games"=>array(
        3=>array(
            "matches"=>array(
                array(
                    "winner"=>"winner",
                    "player1id"=>"player1id",
                    "player2id"=>"player2id"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
print_r(array_merge_recursive($tempArray,$matches));
```

<strike>[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/enpXf#v520)</strike>
[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/sIIQR#v520)

**Edit**

`$tempArray["games"]` and `$tempArray["games"][index]["matches"]` are both numeric arrays, so `array_merge` will append, not override. If you need to **modify** existing value instead of **add** new value, directly modify like

```
$tempArray["games"][index]["matches"][$matchid]["winner"]="winner";
```

Comment: thanks again..I tried but I want the data store in matches[my_match_id].. with this example I tried the data was stored at the end..

Comment: ok so directly how can I do it..                         $arrne['games'][$matchid]['matches']['winner'] ="winner";               This way??

Comment: @user2234992 Isn't that what I have showed you? `["games"][3]["matches"]` in my example.

Comment: So I basically want game array,then its first matches array(already presetn in json) to hold these 3 valus,but must have index of my matchid..If you guide here??

Comment: ya your right.. so in place of 3 I need a php variable, how do I do that.. $matchid..

Comment: @user2234992 Since `["games"]` is a numeric array, the first `["matches"]` is `["games"][0]["matches"]`.

Comment: so I want a array after match[0][mymatchid] followed by theses 3 values..please help @Passerby

Comment: @user2234992 Sorry I made a mistake on my answer. Fixed and updated, please check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28882/discussion-between-user2234992-and-passerby)